# TransferUtility Does not trigger onProgresschanged

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I am working on a project where I want to upload files after developer authentication is complete. I am using AWS Cognito for authentication. Problem here is sometimes TransferUtility does not trigger onProgresschanged. Although it does not trigger onprogresschanged but the file is getting uploaded. I want to show a progressbar on the UI for every upload.It is working sometimes and sometimes it is not working.

Here is how I am uploading files.

```
    public void upload() {

    ClientConfiguration configuration = new ClientConfiguration();
    configuration.setProtocol(Protocol.HTTP);
    configuration.setSocketTimeout(5 * 10000);
    configuration.setConnectionTimeout(5 * 10000);
    configuration.setMaxErrorRetry(3);

    if(sS3Client==null) {
        sS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials,configuration);
    }
    sTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(sS3Client,
        this.ctx);

   observer = sTransferUtility.upload("bucketer", "Filename", "file");

   observer.setTransferListener(new UploadListener(progress));

   }

   private class UploadListener implements TransferListener {

    ProgressBar progressBar;
    public UploadListener(ProgressBar progress){
        this.progressBar = progress;

    }

    @Override
    public void onStateChanged(int i, TransferState transferState) {

        Log.d("STATUS CHANGED:".concat(String.valueOf(i)),transferState.toString());


        switch (transferState.toString())
        {
            case "IN_PROGRESS":
            {
                Log.d("IN_PROGRESS", "IN_PROGRESS");
            }
            break;
            case "COMPLETED":
            {
                Log.d("COMPLETED COMPLETED", "COMPLETED");


            }
            break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(int i, long l, long l1) {

        updator();

        this.progressBar.setProgress(transferprogres);



    }

    @Override
    public void onError(int i, Exception e) {

        Log.d("UPOLADING ERROR:",String.valueOf(e));

    }
    }


   public void updator(){
        transferprogres = (int) ((double) observer.getBytesTransferred() * 100 / observer.getBytesTotal());

}
```

The code above is a part of total project. For more details comment.
Why is it showing weird performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Aws S3 TransferService Upload failing without errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35555414/aws-s3-transferservice-upload-failing-without-errors) and https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/issues/101. In short, v2.2.12 requires user to manage the life cycle of transfer listeners as transfer utility keeps only weak references of them. You can make the listener or the observer as class variable to prevent it from garbage collected. Anyway, we are tweaking the listeners in future releases. Sorry for the trouble and please stay tuned.

Comment: I don't think I understood what you said fully. But will you please provide me a sample code of what you said(listener or the observer as class variable to prevent it from garbage collected). It helps me a lot.

Comment: This is improved in v2.2.13 release. Please check out its release notes: https://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/Android/4091812718909809

Comment: Everything went fine till today after I added updated version of aws sdk.But Suddenly Don't know what happened TransferUtility is not triggering onProgresschanged. help please

Comment: @sandesh Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35555414/aws-s3-transferservice-upload-failing-without-errors/35571792#35571792